# Database or feed of software vulnerabilities, aggregated and with correlations

Tags: security

Is there a comprehensive free and open source database of aggregated and correlated software vulnerabilities available anywhere?

Comment: @Issy I requested the migration

Comment: Did you check with OD if they'd welcome it? I'm not active over there, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: What kind of aggregation do you want? What kind of correlations do you want? Please give real-world examples of what the data should include.

Comment: Please [read this](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like) and improve your question accordingly

Comment: @JanDoggen I will improve

Answer (score 2):

Given that there was nothing, I started a project https://github.com/nexb/vulnerablecode that is supported by NLnet.nl https://nlnet.nl/project/vulnerabilitydatabase/ and that will eventually deliver a free and open database of aggregated and correlated software package vulnerabilities, built in Python and delivered as public domain data.